# How do I find my" vote-up" history?

Tags: support, up-votes, recent-activity

Before, I found an answer to a problem that I had in stack overflow and I voted up for it. Now I am encountering the same problem, I recall the solution but not the syntax and I can't find it anywhere.

How to check my old votes-up history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find in profile vote tab

> [image]